# Can't get variable out of URL

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have been trying to get a value out of my route but it wont work.

My Route:

```
Route::post('/credentials/{info}');
```

My controller function:

```
public function getInfo()
{
     dd($info);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to be this:

```
public function getInfo($info)
{
    dd($info);
}
```

And route needs to be like this:

```
Route::post('/credentials/{info}', 'ControllerName@FunctionName')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the method to accept that parameter if you want it passed to it by the router:

```php
public function getInfo($info)
{
    dd($info);
}
```

[Laravel 6 Docs - Controllers - Defining Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#defining-controllers)

[Laravel 6 Docs - Routing - Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-parameters)